# Assessing the accuracy of zero-inflated beta regression models

Tags: r, regression, zero-inflation, beta-regression, gamlss

I have fitted a zero-inflated beta regression model to my data in R, using the gamlss package.

However, I am unsure of how to assess the fit of the model to my data, i.e. finding a coefficient of determination.

Does anyone know if this can be easily calculated from a zero-inflated beta regression model?

Comment: The function you have to use is **plot(summary)**